# function as round for large number

Tags: function, rounding

I want to function, such as round

When I put the following code in the page :

```
round('247632176321761768127861761576158795796157615761576');
```

Shows me the following:

```
 2.4763217632176E+50
```

i want a function witch :

1>remove comma `,`
2>dont make the number like this 
3>for php

I ask you a quick solution and thanks

Comment: Please post the code you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`round`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function with a precision value:

```
echo round(247632176321761768127861761576158795796157615761576,10);
```

Outputs:

```
2.4763217632176E+50
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said it is for PHP look at the Manual page for [Round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php).